# scala filter a list of lists of tuples

Tags: list, scala, filter

I have a list of lists with tuples (char, Int) like

```
val raw = List(List((a,0), (b,0)), List((a,1), (b,0)), List((a,2), (b,0)), List((a,0), (b,1)), List((a,1), (b,1)), List((a,2), (b,1)), List((a,0), (b,2)), List((a,1), (b,2)), List((a,2), (b,2)))`
```

I want to filter out all tuples with where the Int is 0. So the result should be:

```
List(List(), List((a,1)), List((a,2)), List((b,1)), List((a,1), (b,1)), List((a,2), (b,1)), List((b,2)), List((a,1), (b,2)), List((a,2), (b,2)))
```

I tried to do a map and then a filter but the compiler complains with `incompatible types: ((Int, Char) => Boolean expected but found ((Int, Char) => Unit)`

```
raw.map(_.filter(tuple => match {
  (_,0) => false
  (_,_) => true
})
```

Were do I go wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the correct one:

```
raw.map(_.filter(_._2 != 0))
```

Comment: Thanks As often with scala: less code best results.

Answer (score 2):

This is close to what you tried:

```
raw.map(_.filter({
  case (_,0) => false
  case (_,_) => true
}))
```